# Problem in Angular HTML template with ternary statement

Tags: angular

I have a ternary statement in an Angular HTML template. But when the statement returns false, the data is not distributed to all 6 columns.

```html
<td colspan="getNrOfColumnHeaders() ? 8 : 6">
    {{(serverError ? 'SERVER_ERROR_TABLE_MSG' : 'NO_DATA') | translate}}
</td>
```

Anyone any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: You aren't *binding* to that attribute. Look in dev tools, you'll probably see you're setting the literal value `getNrOfColumnHeaders() ? 8 : 6`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to bind to the attribute dynamically so that Angular knows it has to update the value when it changes, so you need `[colspan]` instead of `colspan`:

```html
<td [colspan]="getNrOfColumnHeaders() ? 8 : 6">
  {{(serverError ? 'SERVER_ERROR_TABLE_MSG' : 'NO_DATA') | translate}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that getNrOfColumnHeaders return boolean and add brackets to colsap attribute like this.

```
 <td [attr.colspan]="getNrOfColumnHeaders() ? 8 : 6">
          {{(serverError ? 'SERVER_ERROR_TABLE_MSG' : 'NO_DATA') | translate}}
    </td>
```